# Checking if a set of tuple contains items from another set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, tuples

Let's say I have a set of tuples like this:

```
foo = {('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C')}
var = {'A', 'C', 'B'}
```

I want to check if every item from var is in any place in the set of tuples and returning True if it is and False if it isn't.
I tried with this but I don't have luck so far.

```
all((x for x in var) in (a,b) for (a,b) in foo)
Desired output : True
Actual output : False
```

However if:

```
var = {'A','C','D'}
```

I want it to return False, the logic is checking if the strings 'know' eachother.

Alright, let's explain this, for my last var.

```
A is paired with C, C is paired D, however D is not paired with A.
```

For my first logic,

```
A is paired with B,B is paired with C,C is paired with B, C is paired with A, Everyone 'knows' each other.
```

.

Comment: So what is it exactly that you want? Do you want to check if every element in var exists somewhere in foo? Or if just 1 does?

Comment: @mrdomoboto I edited, check now.

Comment: Yes, I've deleted my answer because now I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you mean if *all* the elements of each tuple in `foo` are in `var`???

Comment: There, I explained now.

Answer (score 2):

Generate all the pairs you expect to be present and see if they're there with a subset check:

```
from itertools import combinations

def _norm(it):
    return {tuple(sorted(t)) for t in it}

def set_contains(foo, var):
    return _norm(combinations(var, 2)) <= _norm(foo)

print(set_contains({('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C')},
                   {'A', 'C', 'B'}))  # True

print(set_contains({('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C')},
                   {'A', 'C', 'D'}))  # False
```

It may be possible to reduce on the amount of sorting, depending on how exactly `combinations` works (I'm not 100% sure what to make of the docs) and if you reuse either `foo` or `var` several times and can thus sort one of the parts just once beforehand.

Comment: This is better than my approach.

Comment: Although, may I suggest using `set(itertools.chain(*foo))` rather than `set(sum(foo...`

Comment: Pretty much what I want, but still, If I want to check {'A','C','D'} it should False, I should have mentioned in my posts, sorry. It checks if they strings are 'related'.

Comment: @Alex Hall I tried to explain my logic as much as possible.

Comment: Can you implement _norm into other function?

Comment: @HappyUnicorn I don't understand your question. You can reuse it elsewhere if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean to return everything with one line, not creating another function

Comment: @HappyUnicorn you can repeat the logic without the function but it's not a good idea. There's nothing wrong with having an extra function.

Comment: 1 more thing. What does <= means?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foo = {('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C')}
var = {'A', 'C', 'B'}

for elem in var:
    if any(elem in tuples for tuples in foo):
        print(True)
```

Comment: The function needs to return True or False, not print True 0 to many times.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as 'compact' as the others but works the same.

```
for x in var:
    for y in foo:
        if x in y:
            print('Found %s in %s' % (x, y))
        else:
            print('%s not in %s' % (x, y))

B not in ('C', 'D')
B not in ('A', 'C')
Found B in ('A', 'B')
Found B in ('B', 'C')
A not in ('C', 'D')
Found A in ('A', 'C')
Found A in ('A', 'B')
A not in ('B', 'C')
Found C in ('C', 'D')
Found C in ('A', 'C')
C not in ('A', 'B')
Found C in ('B', 'C')
```